# Looking for expandable tableview to convert my JSON tree structure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview, expandablelistview

I want to convert my below JSON tree structure to expandable tableview. JSON tree can be changed dynamically from a server, which can contain Childs up to multiple internal levels.

```
{
  "Tree": {
    "node": [
      {
        "node": [
          {
            "node": null
          },
          {
    
            "node": [
              {
                "node": null
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "node": [
          {
            "node": null
          },
          {
            "node": null
          },
          {
            "node": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Concept of Multi-level sectioned table.

Comment: Yes, Similar to it. I checked some libraries, but all looks static and ends to level 2.

Comment: try this - https://github.com/genkernel/TreeView

Comment: That may help you : github.com/genkernel/TreeView OR github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView

Comment: @AmitBhavsar How did you achieve it? Can you share some example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [KJExpandableTableTree](https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/KJExpandableTableTree) library if you want to create `dynamic tree`structure using `JSON` in UITableview.

- It also provides static initialization.